# Refreshing Data - Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, refresh

I need help to made auto-refresh for my stored procedure and fill datatable with new informations. I need suggestions, I tried to use Timer who clear datatable and execute stored procedure again, but I think that's bad solution.

My current code:

```
 Public Sub Efficiency_Procedure()
    _eff.Clear()
    Dim dtStart As String

    dtStart = FormatDateTime(DateTime.Today)

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("spEfficiencyConfB", MyConnection)
    Dim outParam As SqlParameter
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@startTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtStart
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@stopTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtStart
    outParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@nrOut", SqlDbType.Int)
    outParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

    If MyConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        MyConnection.Open()
    End If

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)

    _eff.Load(dr)

    dr.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()

    If MyConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        MyConnection.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: We can't see much of your code here. But if you need to refresh a grid with current data you are pretty much going to have to run the stored procedure each time. Maybe your procedure needs some performance help? Also, you have the same value for startTime and stopTime...not sure if that is on purpose or not.

Comment: Yes, currently i'm getting data only for today. I will fix it. How can I made a real time getting data (when new informations is in db, to automaticly update my datatable)? Does not need to be stored procedure.